# SWFAddress setValue() Method Triggers URL Change Event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, swfaddress

I am building a Flex application that utilizes SWFAddress. Whenever I update the hijacked URL via SWFAddress' `SWFAddress.setValue()` method, I notice it causes the `SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE` event to dispatch, causing my page to go through its update cycle again.

Is there a method within SWFAddress to "silently" update the hijacked URL, such that the `SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE` event is not dispatched?

The only way around this that I can think of right now is to remove the event listener, change the URL, then add it back. But that seems... really... inefficient. Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hey just checked out the source code, there's nothing in there that lets you block the event, if it's a new value then the event is dispatched (it looks like it skips doing this during init but in all other cases if the change occurs it's dispatched).  You can modify the source since it's available and add your own boolean to SWFAddress to stop it from dispatching the event, otherwise like you already said removing/adding the listener is an option, if it's only one object having the listener added/removed I don't think performance would be impacted.

Comment: @shaunhusain Thank you for looking into it. That is what I ended up doing. If you want to cut and paste your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey just checked out the source code, there's nothing in there that lets you block the event, if it's a new value then the event is dispatched (it looks like it skips doing this during init but in all other cases if the change occurs it's dispatched). You can modify the source since it's available and add your own boolean to SWFAddress to stop it from dispatching the event, otherwise like you already said removing/adding the listener is an option, if it's only one object having the listener added/removed I don't think performance would be impacted.